# Styles in .scss file not applied

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I have a react app and use `.scss` files for styling.

My index.js looks like this:

```
import './App.scss';

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App/>
    </React.StrictMode>,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My `App.scss` looks like this:

```
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
    height: 100%;
}

body,
:global(#root) {
    min-height: 100%;
    color: var(--primary-font-color);
    font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
}

h1 {
    color: var(--primary-font-color);
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 600;
    line-height: 36px;
}

:root {

    /*Colors */
    --primary-color: #f6f5f2;
}
```

Now my problem is that all the styles apart from `*,*::before,*::after` and `:root` are not applied.
In the browser console I can see that the `App.scss` is used and the `*,*::before,*::after` styles are applied. Also all vars from `:root` can be found there.

I want to use the `App.scss` file for global styles, but the only way I found to apply them is with an `@import("App.scss")` in a `component.module.scss`. Importing the `App.scss` to every module results in as many duplicates as imports. Is this the intended way to handle `scss` styles?

Answer (score 1):

Sass is not recommended to use today for global styles, because as they wrote -> it can generate more files than you want -> effect is that you have worse performance

This information we can read on their main page

I recommend you use once simple CSS file for variables, global styles then easily you can reuse them and if you wanna use Sass as a developer then go-ahead for the rest of styling

Best!

Comment: This answer does not address the problem in the question.

Comment: Thats true, but it a noteworthy workaround, which could solve my problem. If the inteded way is to import the App.css in every module I use.

Comment: Posted as new answer, because in comment longer code line is not displayed in nice looking way :)

Answer (score 1):

For example what you can do

App.css:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Lato, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  transition: all 0.3s linear;
}

:root {
  --facebook-color: #507dc0;
}
```

And then:

Login.scss

```
body {
  .login {
    background-color: var(--facebook-color);
  }
}
```

Of course this is only example.

Comment: I tried it, but have the same result. Only  `*,*::before,*::after` are applied and none of the other tags.

Answer (score 1):

I found the a solution:

Looks like it was the `:global(#root)` which caused the problem. Removing it makes the other styles applied no matter if they are in a `.scss` or `.css` file.